# Use getter and setter in swift to set variable extension

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to set a value for an SKSpriteNode. So, I made an extension to SKSpriteNode called HAKEK

I've tried this

```
var HAKEK: Int {
        get {
            return self.HAKEK

        }
        set {
            self.HAKEK = newValue

        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work cause it keep returning it self, so how do I let It get its own value which is set in the setter?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025340/property-getters-and-setters, it will help understanding.

Comment: What do you _really_ want to achieve?

Comment: You *cannot* add a stored property in an extension: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025785/swift-why-cannot-add-store-property-in-extension-whats-the-different-between. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426780/how-to-have-stored-properties-in-swift-the-same-way-i-had-on-objective-c for some kind of workaround.

Comment: I want to set a value for some SKSpriteNodes, a value could be lives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create stored properties in extensions as others have mentioned.  Normally I would agree with others in using associated objects, but with `SKNode`, there is an even better property to work with.
It is called `userData`, and it is designed to allow your nodes to hold custom data.

```
extension SKSpriteNode
{
    var HAKEK: Int {
        get {
            return self.userData?["HAKEK"] ?? 0

        }
        set {
            self.userData = self.userData ?? [String:AnyObject]()
            self.userData["HAKEK"] = newValue

        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I would not extend SKSpriteNode if this property is not going to be available to all SKSpriteNodes.  If this is a unique case, you may want to sub class, which means this extension isn't even needed.