# the current Context is always nil

Tags: ios, uiview

the current Context is always nil

```
extension UIView {
    var screenShotImage : UIImage? {
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( self.bounds.size, true, 0 )
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        print("Context equal nil")
            return nil
            }
    context.translateBy(x: -bounds.origin.x, y: -bounds.origin.y)
    layer.render(in: context)
    guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        print("fail to take view shot")
            return nil
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling this?

Answer (score -1):

Would you mind changing the `Computed Property` inside of an `extension` into a `instance method` declaration as follows

```
import UIKit
extension UIView {

    func getScreenshot() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( self.bounds.size, true, 0 )
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            print("Context equal nil")
            return nil
        }
        context.translateBy(x: -bounds.origin.x, y: -bounds.origin.y)
        layer.render(in: context)
        guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            print("fail to take view shot")
            return nil
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Which works fine. This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025785/swift-why-cannot-add-store-property-in-extension-whats-the-different-between) explains the reason briefly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean , but I realize something else that Cause this problem , the problem is my view size depends on a stack view inside it , when i remove this stack view it works fine

Comment: i mean, you used computed property (a property who's value is computed in a block) inside a extension (instead of a class definition). Whenever you declared such property inside a extension it's inside the scope of the class, it's becoming a static member of the class, every instance of the class has the same single `screenShotImage` object. So i removed it from computed property and changed it to method, which also in a class scope which is ok.

Comment: I don't know why removing your stack view it work's fine. My guess is multiple view object is instantiated and the computed property can't keep track of those. But in that case, above code (method version) must work.

Comment: How computed property become a static member of class? , I don't think that